# Running super().__init__(value) where value is an @property

Tags: python

I'm just trying to grok how exactly Python handles this behind the scenes.  So take this code snippet (from Effective Python by Brett Slatkin):

```
class Resistor(object):
    def __init__(self, ohms):
        self.ohms = ohms
        self.voltage = 0
        self.current = 0


class VoltageResistor(Resistor):
    def __init__(self, ohms):
        super().__init__(ohms)
        self._voltage = 0

    @property
    def ohms(self):
        return self._ohms

    @ohms.setter
    def ohms(self, ohms):
        if ohms <= 0:
            raise ValueError('{o} ohms must be > 0'.format(o=ohms))
        self._ohms = ohms

    @property
    def voltage(self):
        return self._voltage

    @voltage.setter
    def voltage(self, voltage):
        self._voltage = voltage
        self.current = self._voltage / self.ohms

VoltageResistor(-1) # fails
```

Running the `super()` call invokes the property check so that you can't instantiate with a zero or negative value.  What is confusing me to me is that I would think that since the the `__init__(ohms)` call is being ran on the superclass, shouldn't it be in a different scope (the scope of the superclass) and thus exempt from invoking the `@property` check?

Comment: Nope; `self` is still an instance of `VoltageResistor` inside `Resistor.__init__`; scope has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scope doesn't come into play when working with object's attributes.  Consider the following:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

def foo():
    a = A()
    a.a = 2
    return a

def bar(a):
    print(a.a)

bar(foo())
```

This example code will print 2.  Note that within the scope of `bar`, there *is* no way to gain access to the scope of `foo` or even `A.__init__`.  The class *instance* is carrying along all of it's attributes/properties with it (and a reference to it's class which has a reference to *it's* superclass, etc).

In your code, when you call `VoltageResistor`, an instance of `VoltageResistor` is created and passed to `__init__` as `self`.  When you call `super.__init__(self)`, that `VoltageResistor` instance is passed along to `Resistor.__init__`.  When it does `self.ohms = ohms`, python sees that `self.ohms` resolves to a property and you get the error.  The tl;dr; here is that `self` is an instance of `VoltageResistor` and **when working with attributes, the object on which the attributes are accessed is what is important, not the current scope**).

Answer (score 1):

To supplement the above excellent answer, just add the following line in the parent's constructor to get a better idea of what is going on:

```
class Resistor(object):
    def __init__(self, ohms):
        print (type(self).__name__)
        self.ohms = ohms
```

It will print `VoltageResistor` and then throw a `ValueError`. The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) confirm this:

> If **c is an instance of C**, c.x will invoke the getter, **c.x = value will invoke the setter** and del c.x the deleter.

Answer (score 0):

`ValueError` Happens there because `VoltageResistor.__init__` calls `Resistor.__init__`, which assigns `self.ohms = -1`. That assignment causes the `@ohms.setter` method from `VoltageResistor` to be called, and it immediately runs the validation code before object construction has completed.